Why would I not use a single SSL cert with multiple wildcard SANs?
Google uses a single SSL cert with multiple wildcard SANs for all its domains. You can check this here.
Are there potential disadvantages to this? Does a large cert present processing/latency issues for TLS clients?
I think in the past organisations didn't not do this as it meant updating the cert every time you wanted to add a new SAN, but given that we're moving to 90 day certs, is that really an issue any more?
I think organisations were also concerned about "blast radius" if a cert expired or was revoked, but again, with modern monitoring and automation systems, is that still an issue?
Why would an organisation maintain 100s of certs, on a 90 day renewal cycle, if its possible to maintain a single cert?

Why would an organisation maintain 100s of certs most organizations don't "maintain" certificates, or do a poor job of it. That said, everything thing about the "maintenance" still needs to occur (or more likely be neglected) if it has a SAN with multiple names. Also, as with most decisions, cost is 10x more of a factor. A SAN certificate costs $15 more? Forget about it.

If the same server is used for multiple domains it makes usually sense to use the same certificate for multiple domains (i.e. SAN). Using many more granular certificates instead might actually cut down on size of the TLS handshake though since the certificates are smaller. This might increase performance in some cases, but it complicates setup.
If the different domains are used on different servers though it is better to use different certificates and also different private keys for these certificates. This limits the impact of a potential server compromise to the domains with certificates and key on this specific server only and does not affect other domains on other servers.

It depends how your wildcard certificate was deployed.
If you place a single wildcard certificate on an Internet facing load-balancer, then it makes sense.  Why manage potentially hundreds of certificates on the LB, when one will suffice?  If the LB is compromised, then one or a hundred certs doesn't matter - they're all assumed to be compromised (OK, it takes more time to replace a hundred, but that's small fry in comparison to the reputational damage).  That was part of the deal when you decided to use a TLS terminating LB.
If you have multiple Internet facing servers, then copying a wildcard certificate (and the private key naturally) to all of them is a risk which can be avoided.  If you copy them, then if one server was compromised, all are effectively compromised.  That again would severely damage your reputation, which is why you installed certs in the first place isn't it?.  Instead, it would be wise to have a certificate per server in this scenario, as if one server is compromised, the others retain their reputation.
